# how to check that inlining occurred

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I would like to massively use `inline` in my project to speed up performance.

As far as I know the compiler *might* apply inline or not; it is up to the compiler.

It is not clear to me what I can do to make this possible, but before going that direction, do you know a way to check that inlinining really occurred or not in the output binary?

Comment: You do not want to force inlining indiscriminately. The compiler makes a decision to inline based on trying to make the application as quick as possible (default is speed: You can optimize for other things). If you force inlineing you may actually make the application run slower. Let the compiler do its job and make the correct decision (humans are usually very bad at making this decision).

Comment: HI Can you point out some example about how possibly inlining can hurt the performance? I probably didn't get the real point that is this one you mentioned. In my head I alwayss thought that inline implies no call stack so I save CPU/time on that..how it can make it slower?

Comment: A simple example is that a large function multiple times in a inner loop could cause your you're code to overfill a cache line, where the loop and the called function could have otherwise fit within the cache. A cache miss is one of the most expensive operations a modern CPU can perform. In all it's best to just trust your compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `gcc -Winline` to get warnings when an inline function is not inlined.

Use `__attribute__ ((always_inline))` to force functions to be inlined.

Having said that, be warned that you can screw up performance, compile time and get huge code bloat if you use inlining injudiciously.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion but probably I don't get how can slow the performance down? Can you point me out a small real-world example?

Comment: You can easily wreck performance with inlining, e.g. by making a loop too large to fit in L1 instruction cache.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the MS compiler you might want to enable [warning C4710](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yd3056cz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to get a warning for functions not inlined.

Comment: HI! I used to work with MS and I completely forgot about that warning. You are right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `gcc -S` option to generate assembler output, and then inspect the output in your favourite text editor.

But, the compiler is often a better judge than you of when inlining will actually improve performance. Don't be too hasty to force it; profile your code and see if inlining actually is faster.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is probably smarter about this than you are, but ignoring that, assuming you don't have any special compiler flags enabled, you can dump the name list and find if the function has been generated.

```
static int foo(int x)
{
  return(x*x);
}

main()
{
  int x=1;
  foo(x);
}
```

To test

```
not seth> gcc -o /tmp/foo /tmp/main1.c
not seth> nm /tmp/foo | grep foo
00000000004004c4 t foo
not seth> gcc -O -o /tmp/foo /tmp/main1.c
not seth> nm /tmp/foo | grep foo
```

Comment: Just dumping the symbols won't tell you whether the compiler inlined the function wherever it was called.  If the compiler can determine that the function MIGHT be called in a way that can't be inlined, it is required to provide a callable routine, which would force the symbol to be present, even if it does manage to inline it everywhere else.

Comment: @Seth Robertson: Still, rare as it might be to have function pointers, the fact is that the presence of the symbol does not indicate absence of inlining. The compiler might very well just generate the symbol "just in case".

Comment: This depends on the compiler, of course, but gcc for example only does that with special compiler flags.

Comment: David Rodríguez - dribeas is right, and this answer is therefore wrong: it only shows that inling didn't _fully_ happen, and there's still an outlined copy present. But the question was whether inlining happened at all. Inlining can be decided on a per-call base, so it's quite possible that it happens for only some calls to a particular function.

Comment: Your example program is bad. Any good compile will compile it just like a program with an empty `main` function, as all the code has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The `inline` keyword has actually little to do with optimization. Most compilers will inline a function *call* (the function itself may have to be compiled separately, eg. if you take its address somewhere else) regardless of whether the `inline` keyword is present or not.

In fact, even if one called function is in another translation unit, a clever linker may inline it at link time (MSVC provides this feature as "link time code generation"). It requires strong cooperation between the compiler and the linker though.

The *raison d'être* of the `inline` keyword is to allow [non template] functions to break the One Definition Rule, and thus to be defined in header files. The actual inlining of the function will be decided by the compiler based on various heuristics and optimization flags passed to it, and **not** based on the `inline` keyword.

So massively using `inline` will probably do absolutely nothing about performance. If you're worried about performance, use a profiler to determine where your program spends its time (often where you don't expect it to), and act accordingly, by optimizing the *actual* bottleneck.